# UnhandledPromiseRejection when a promise is rejected and added to an array of promises

Tags: node.js, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

I have the promise in **function2** which is rejected and added into the array of promises in  **function1**. The code ends with **UnhandledPromiseRejection**. Can you please help me to understand why the promise is not successfully returned from **function1** and caught in **test** function?

```
const sleep = require("sleep-promise");

function function1() {
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(function2());
    return sleep(1000).then(() => {
        return Promise.all(promises)
    });
}

function function2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject("failed");
    })
}

async function test() {
    try {
        await function1();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

test();
```

output:

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "failed".]
```

Comment: A promise that rejects must be caught in at least one place *at the moment it rejects*, or there'll be an unhandled rejection. Your `promises.push(function2());` doesn't handle it immediately. (You've also forgotten to return the sleep call - `function1` returns `undefined`)

Comment: Is there a way how to accumulate list of promises and evaluate their state later on?

(thanks, I've fixed the missing return in the original post)

Comment: Evaluate, sure - but you must catch *somewhere* immediately

Comment: Got it and `promises.push(function2().catch(() => promiseRejected = true));` is how would you identify a rejection?

Comment: Only if you actually use `promiseRejected` somewhere - an empty block would make more sense otherwise